# How to migrate files together with additional fields

Tags: 8, files, migrations

In my Drupal 8.4 installation I use the module [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity). In the module are defined a few additional fields: 'author', 'title', 'alt',... My migration works. The files are imported, but the additional fields are after the import empty.

The complete YML (modules\my_migration_module\config\install\migrate_plus.migration.files.yml) looks like:

```
langcode: en
status: true
id: files
migration_group: import_xml
label: 'Import the test XML file'
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  urls: 'http://example.org/test.xml'
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  item_selector: /imports/files
  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: ID
      selector: ./@id
    -
      name: title
      label: Title
      selector: ./@title
    -
      name: alt
      label: Alt
      selector: ./@alt
    -
      name: author
      label: Author
      selector: ./@author
    -
      name: filename
      label: Filename
      selector: ./@filename
    -
      name: uri
      label: URI
      selector: ./@uri
    -
      name: target
      label: Target
      selector: ./@target
  keys:
    - id
  ids:
    id:
      type: string
process:
  field_alt: alt
  field_title: title
  field_author: author
  filename: filename
  uri:
    plugin: download
    source:
      - uri
      - target
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
  source_path_property: uri
  destination_path_property: target
template: null
```

E.g. for the field title I have tried:

```
field_title: title
title: title
field_title/field_title_value: title
field_title/field_title_value: title
field_title/field_title: title
file__field_titel/field_title_value: title
file__field_titel/field_title: title
```

I have found a solution for a similar problem in Drupal 7: [How to migrate fields attached to files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109152/how-to-migrate-fields-attached-to-files) I'm not sure, how can I implement this in Drupal 8.

Comment: Do you migrate files with additional fields from d7 to d8? Have you tried to implement a custom source plugin? There you can specify on prepareRow()   function some additional fields to migrate.

Comment: No, I import the files from XML.

Comment: Have you tried using `simple_xml` instead of `xml` as `data_parser_plugin`? I also had a some problems with a XML import that were solved by changing nothing execpt the data_parser_plugin

Comment: I have tried to change 'data_parser_plugin: xml' to 'data_parser_plugin: simple_xml'. But it did not helped. And I've got then the warning "Illegal string offset 'x-default' ContentEntityBase.php:949",

Comment: I have found the following issue. May be it is the reason, why the additional fields are not imported. See: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2822545

Answer (score 1):

The YML code is correct. But there is an issue in Drupal core: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2822545

There is also a patch. I have tested the patch and it works:
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2822545-cannot_update_file_properties-6.patch

The patch can be installed with Composer:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
        "drupal/core": "8.4.6",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "extra": {
        "patches": {
           "drupal/core": {
             "Solve the issue when migrating files with additional fields": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2822545-cannot_update_file_properties-6.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```